# shell script/command line to read most recent timestamp from a log file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a log file containing event timestamps. I want to get the most recent timestamp out of the log file, and have this number updated whenever the log file is written to.

The events sometimes arrive out of order, sometimes by a matter of hours because they're buffered up when there are outages, so I can't just take the bottom line of the log file.

I'm thinking about running `tail -f|grep` on the log file, piping the output to some variant of `date` to convert the formatted time to Unix epoch time, and piping that to a script which will remember the biggest number seen so far.

Does anybody have a script which will do this?

Edit: the date formats are YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, i.e. 2012-02-02 04:15:15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the current largest value:

```
$ tail -F youfile.log |
> awk 'NR == 1 {max=$0; print max} $0 > max {max = $0; print max}'
```

#### Example

```
$ printf "2010-10-01 01:02:02 a
2010-09-30 02:03:04 b\n2010-08-29 01:02:02 c\n2010-10-01 01:02:03 d\n" |
> awk 'NR == 1 {max=$0; print max} $0 > max {max = $0; print max}'
```

#### Output

```
2010-10-01 01:02:02 a
2010-10-01 01:02:03 d
```

Comment: for your example date format it works. but will fail on :for example: 02.11.2012 00:00:00 and 25.10.1999 00:00:00. OP should give Date pattern. If it could be converted to ms by date cmd, it would be good.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your timestamps are in format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or something similar.

```
watch 'tail -n 20 yourfile.log | LANG=C sort | tail -n 1'
```

or if you prefer to see the history:

```
while true
do
  tail -n 20 yourfile.log | LANG=C sort | tail -n 1
  sleep 2
done
```

Use `LANG=C` before `sort` because `sort` can behave differently depending on your locals.